# c# Visual studio after pubish application generate errors with database

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2015, publish

My application use SQL Server Database. When i run my app in VS everything work fine, but this app must br running in other computer, so i decide to create instalation package(publish in VS). In my PC app instal and run well, but when i install it in another computer app runn well to moment when it have to access to the database. It generate errors [Error exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KfLS.png)

Link to github project: [JOBBOERSE](https://github.com/R0ut/JOBBOERSE)

Comment: Could you add the errors in text form to this question? I clicked on the link to the image and it was so small that nobody can read it.

Comment: Sorry, for this img now it look good

Comment: Link to instalation files that VS generate: http://www.filedropper.com/programtest

Comment: Could you please add a translation of the error message in english? Also, the error message says that it can't access the LocalDB database with the specified connection string. Did you make sure that there is a LocalDB installation available when your application is deployed?

Comment: I will add translation tommorow

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KfLS.png - error exception in english

Answer (score 0):

Can you navigate to the path specified in your app.config (\AddressBook.mdf). Does your installation properly install the DB file in the same manner you have been testing locally with?

```
 <connectionStrings> 
         <add name="JOBBOERSE.Properties.Settings.AddresBookConnectionString" 
             connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AddresBook.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
 </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: this is path to AddressBook.mdf
C:\Users\Janek\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\DXHWT9HR.ZV4\AddressBook.mdf

Comment: After you install it can you navigate to that path on the machine where it does not work. How are you setting up the database on the target machine?

Comment: On target machine i download and install this SqlLocalDB.msi from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062 thats all what i`v done in target machine. I think that .mdf file path is wrong

Comment: Perhaps you can change your connection string to |InstallDir|\AddresBook.mdf where InstallDir is your application directory or some other folder of your choosing.

Comment: How i can do it for example i want to install app in c:/JOBBOERSE and database here too

Comment: Change it to AttachDbFilename=C:\JOBBOERSE\AddresBook.mdf;

Comment: and application will install too in c:\JOBBOERSE ?

Comment: When i change path to C:\JOBBOERSE\AddresBook.mdf; and add AddresBook.mdf here it work well on pc that i have project and VS but when i do the same in target machine it won`t work, probably i have to install some database program/library etc. on target machine but what ?

Comment: There used to be msi merge modules for sql server client library installations, however, I have not worked with InstallShield or "On-Click Install" in years. There has to be a redistributable for sql server client connectivity that you can package with your application setup, many products do this.

Comment: What should be installed in target PC to run/use databse

Answer (score 0):

Install SQL Server 2016 version on target PC is the answer for this question. I`v got 2014 version but db file need 2016